# Load external SWFs into SWF and play them in a row

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to load several external SWFs into a main SWF and play them in a row, the loading is no problem, but I don't know how I can detect if a SWF have played and then unload it and load the new one.
This sounds a bit wired, I will explain it in details:
I have 10 .swf Files which are pretty small but they all have different durations. I want to play them in a row, randomly ordered. So I need a parent .swf File which loads the files and plays them. My problem is that I dont know how I can get the play status of the loaded .swf in the main .swf file.

I guess I need to register some event listeners, but I don't know which one since I am completly new to AS and Flash.

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

This might be a duplicate since it is a pretty basic question, but I didn't found anything via search...but I'm new to flash, so I might have searched the wrong terms.

Regards
Nils

Answer (score 0):

If the swfs are just static animations (don't contain any frame jumping code) and just play from start finish, you may be able to access the current frame and total frame properties of the loaded swf and seeing if they are done playing by checking if the values match. A quick check reveals that you may need to use the 'contentLoaderInfo' object inside the Loader object to access the loaded swf's properties.

Or perhaps it can be possible to modify the loaded swfs to throw a complete event when they are done playing that you could catch in the main swf?

However, if the swf you are loading are not AS3, then you'll need to use a LocalConnection object to communicate between them, perhaps querying/passing the current frame and total frames of the swfs.

Comment: The child .swf files are just static animations. I only get your first tip! ;) Why should I throw anything in the child .swf file?! Is it really that complicated?!

Comment: No, you shouldn't need to modify the child .swf files. I was just saying that could be another different method of solving the problem.